# Proxy shell script as app bundle executable

Tags: macos, cocoa

I create an app bundle which has a shell script as main executable.
This then runs "exec /path/to/other/executable" as its last action.
(The reason for this is that I download new executables through an update system, and I don't want to write into the app bundle which typically is in /Applications. Instead I write updates to the user directory, and aim to let the app bundle itself be just a kind of launcher)

The problem is that this makes OS X think that the bundle directory is the one in which the second executable is. This causes it to not respect Info.plist, and all kinds of badness. (If I move the real executable into the MacOS folder of the bundle, everything is peachy, but as I said this is not really an option)

This guide led me to believe that something like this was possible:
http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app

Here they run "exec mono ..." as the last action in their shellscript, where "mono" is a binary residing outside of the app bundle somewhere. And I assume their bundles end up being well behaved.

Is this possible then?

Comment: What about having a symbolic link from Contents/MacOS/AppName in the App bundle to the "real" executable? - I did not try it but perhaps it works.

Comment: That would still require writing into the shared app bundle. When another user logs in the symlink would lead to a different user directory. Overwriting it might not work due to permissions.